# iOS: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

Tags: ios

Getting the following error:

> fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

I am making a registration form application. The app allows users to create custom questions to be added to a form. At the moment I'm using a Singleton design pattern to pass the list of questions between the editing tab and the tab used to display the form.

My singleton class:

```
class Singleton {
    static let sharedInstance = Singleton()
    var questions: [Question] = []
}
```

In the editing form the user will press a button to update the form that people can then fill out. Here is that code and is also where I'm getting the error:

```
var mySingleton: Singleton!

@IBAction func updateForm(sender: AnyObject) {
    for index in mySingleton.questions.count...questionsArray.count {
        mySingleton.questions.append(questionsArray[index])
    }
}
```

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is where the error is occurring:

```
for index in mySingleton.questions.count...questionsArray.count {
    mySingleton.questions.append(questionsArray[index])
}
```

The final index that is looped through is `questionsArray.count`. When you access `questionsArray[questionsArray.count]`, you are outside the bounds of the array. This index should never be accessed.

Instead, change your loop to the following:

```
for index in mySingleton.questions.count..<questionsArray.count {
    mySingleton.questions.append(questionsArray[index])
}
```

The only difference is that `...` becomes `..<`, in order to leave out the last index that is causing the error.

**Edit**: after looking back at the code, it seems likely that `mySingleton` was never set equal to anything. Before this code is executed, you could set `mySingleton = Singleton.sharedInstance`, or simply get rid of `mySingleton` and directly use `Singleton.sharedInstance`.

Comment: The same error still occurs after I fixed that statement. I wouldn't think that indexing too far out of bounds would cause that type of error.

Comment: @AlexCauthen I just noticed something else that seems more likely, check my edit.

Comment: @AlexCauthen Just because the `...` wasn't causing *this* issue doesn't mean that it wouldn't be a separate issue.

Comment: Yes I completely understand, and I appreciate your help. It would have most definitely been an error after this issue was fixed. It is no longer crashing. Thank you.